# Configure KafkaRoutingTemplate from Application yml file

Tags: spring-kafka

we need to send the data to 2 topics which belongs to the two different servers. One is confluent offerings in Azure another is kafka cluster on azure VM.

Now we are using KafkaRoutingTemplate   to send message to the 2 different Kafka Offerings.

But we create 2 producers/factory  via config class ( coding)   - Is there any way to configure 2 producers via application.yml file instead of coding

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bootstrap servers in one of the templates; they can use the same producer factory, but you have to define the templates as beans.

```java
/**
 * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and properties, with
 * autoFlush false. If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
 * {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory} will be created with merged producer properties
 * with the overrides being applied after the supplied factory's properties.
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
 * @since 2.5
 */
public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
```